# How to configure setting of phppgadmin with xampp and postgresql 9.5?

Tags: apache2, php, postgresql, xampp

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Xampp 5.6 and PostgreSQL-9.5

I have already uncommented these lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

but still I this error:

```
Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option.
```

please help me, I still new in Ubuntu

Comment: Have you installed `php5-pgsql`?

Comment: yes, i already install php5-pgsql, and still doesn't work

Comment: i've found solved my own problem, uncomment this line too extension="pgsql.so"

Comment: Good! Please answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment these line in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

extension=php_pgsql.dll

extension="pgsql.so"

then restart xampp service with

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart